# Does MS SQL allow to use multiple queries for different columns in INSERT statement?

Tags: sql-server, insertion

Is it possible to insert values using multiple queries for different columns?
MS SQL allows to write,

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1(COL1) 
SELECT COL1 FROM TABLE2
```

But what if I want to insert one data from one table, and another data from another table? Does MS SQL allow it? If so, what is the syntax?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share sample data and your existing code.

Comment: hint: `Union All`

Comment: You can collect data from different table using JOINING as per requirement. As long as INPUT column number and data type is synced with your selection, there is no issue joining different tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can write any select query like :

> INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COLUMN1, COLUMN2) 
>   SELECT TABLE2.VAL1, TABLE3.VAL2 FROM TABLE2 INNER JOIN TABLE3 ON TABLE2.ID = TABLE3.FID

Comment: If the tables aren't related, nothing will get inserted.